# Silverlight Datagrid and browser close problem

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have what I consider to be a stupid problem with a simple Silverlight application that has a datagrid in it.  One of my columns lets the user edit an attendance number for the current day.  if the user tabs/clicks away after editing, all is saved and good with the binding contract, but if the datagrid edit box has focus and the user closes the browser, the data is not updated in the database.  I am using Silverlight 4 with an observable collection through the standard wcf ria services.

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App.xaml.cs there is an Application_Exit() function.  That function is launched event when the user closes the browser.

in that method, retrieve your current opened window through the RootVisual like that :

```
private void Application_Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (this.RootVisual is MySLApp.MainPage)
   {
      MySLApp.MainPage theMainPage = (MySLApp.MainPage)this.RootVisual;

      theMainPage.myGrid.Commit() // OR SOMETHING LIKE THAT I DONT THINK THE COMMIT EXISTS :)
   }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  It seems that the application.exit event is not being called when the browser is closed.

Comment: Try to put a MessageBox.Show(""); in the Application_Exit() to see if its called.  In my test probject it works (with framework 4.0)

Comment: Yes, i am getting the Application exit event, and i am calling datagrid.commitedit();  it is failing to apply my edits even if i put a message box after the commit call to slow down asynch processing.  Am I missing something?

Comment: i traced it to even getting to my updateRecordAsync call in my webservice and it still does not update.